# ¿De que manera un elemento perteneciente a la categoria de contenido metadata puede modificar la presentacion de un documento HTML?

Tags: html, html5

Estoy estudiando categorías de contenido en el sitio de mozilla, cito lo siguiente:

> Los elementos pertenecientes a la categoría contenido metadata
>   modifican la presentación o el comportamiento del resto del documento,
>   establece vínculos a otros documentos, o se comunica con otra
>   información fuera de rango

`<title>` podría ser un ejemplo de esto porque muestra un titulo al usuario?

cuando se dice que los elementos de categoría metadata modifican la presentación del documento ¿se refiere a que el elemento participa en el flujo de manera que el usuario pueda ver la información que representa el elemento metadata en si?

¿Cuando se dice que modifica la presentación del documento de que habla exactamente? ¿podrían darme algunos ejemplos de etiquetas que cumplen esta condición?

Comment: > Cuando se dice que modifica la presentación del documento Básicamente lo que dice es que el navegador interpretará esos metadatos y mostrará tu sitio web de manera diferente, al decir la presentación del documento se refiere a la forma en el que el navegador representara tu html y es como lo vera el usuario. Estas configuraciones cambian la forma en el que se comporta tu fichero osea tu pagina y como lo dice ahi puedes importar archivos etc. Espero haber ayudado poquito. Saludos.

Comment: Por ejemplo, puedes decirle al navegador si la web acepta que se le haga zoom o no, el zoom por defecto, si quieres que la página se auto actualice sola cada X segundos....

Answer (score 1):

Hay una serie de etiquetas que puede llegar a modificar la forma en que se visualiza la página, como las siguientes etiquetas.

```
<title>Fylo</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./assets/icons/favicon-32x32.png" type="image/x-icon">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

La primera es la que le da el título al sitio web que sueles ver al lado de un icono que normalmente se le llama favicon, que justamente está en la tercera línea abajo de la etiqueta meta.
La siguiente etiqueta es meta que se puede repetir como vez en el ejemplo, pero según sus atributos cumplen diferentes funciones.

- charset="UTF-8" : permite almacenar diferentes caracteres, en caso de que este atributo no este con su valor que es **UTF-8** puede que no se muestren de forma correcta algunas letras como ejemplo nuestra **ñ**.
  La siguiente etiqueta permite una mayor compatibilidad con el navegador, que es el valor: **IE=edge** y la última que está en el ejemplo permite una mejor visualización en diferentes dispositivos.

Ten en cuenta que estas etiquetas que estan dentro del  cumplen con una función de optimizar el **SEO** ( Search Engine Optimization ) que son el conjunto de acciones y técnicas que se emplean para mejorar el posicionamiento (la visibilidad) en buscadores de un sitio web en Internet.

Este articulo en WikiPedia puede ayudarte a entender que es el SEO. [Posicionamiento en buscadores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posicionamiento_en_buscadores)

aqui tambien puedes ver un poco más sobre las etiquetas que van dentro del  [etiquetas dentro del head](https://oregoom.com/html/head/)

Espero haber ayudado.